# cursor "_django_curs_1696_sync_2" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I accidentally deleted my migrations. I later `makemigrations` and `migrate` but when I access certain parts of the app that have `ForeignKey` `references`, I get cursor `"_django_curs_1696_sync_2" does not exist`. How on earth would I go about getting this corrected. This is happening in development and so I fear pushing to production because the same error will arise.?
I tried looking at similar questions but couldn't get one to help solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this problem

1. Delete All files in all app migration folder (Except _ _ init _ _ .py)
2. If use Docker Delete DB Volumes, **Else**  Delete Your DB
3. ReCreate the Database
4. Run `$Python manage.py makemigrations`
5. Run `$Python manage.py migrate`
6. Enjoy IT